# how formatting columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

good day! I understand that this is a simple question, but I can't solve it. I have a format table:
[image]

I want to get the table below, which is obtained based on the breakdown by column
decimal:

[image]
how can I do this?

Comment: In the future, it's extremely helpful to demonstrate what you've tried so far by including a [mre] and explaining explicitly what doesn't work or meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

First [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) both `num` and `epoch`, then [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) the result for L1 and L2's `min` and `max` values. At the tail end, [provide explicit nomenclature for each of the columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) to get the output you've prescribed:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"num": [2, 2, 2, 2], "epoch": [1, 1, 2, 2], "L1": [1, 2, 3, 4], "L2": [11, 14, 12, 16], "decimal": ["min", "max", "min", "max"]})

df = df.groupby(["num", "epoch"])[['L1', 'L2']].agg(['max', 'min']).reset_index()
df.columns = ["num", "epoch", "L1_max", "L1_min", "L2_max", "L2_min"]
```

Result:

```
>>> df
   num  epoch  L1_max  L1_min  L2_max  L2_min
0    2      1       2       1      14      11
1    2      2       4       3      16      12
```